# Removing duplicate from 2 lists (Not on individual) of the same or different indexes

Tags: python, list, duplicates, naivebayes

In Python, I am trying to remove duplicates from two lists simultaneously and not individually. For example, if one list `a` has `[1,2,3]` and another list `b` has `[4,5,6,2]`, then the output of `a` should remain the same but `b` should be changed to `[4,5,6]` removing `[2]` identifying it as a duplicate element in both the lists.

First of all, is my question valid?

This should be regardless of both the list lengths and the number of indexes. I have been trying a lot but couldn't get one proper solution anywhere. One of the codes which I tried was using the naive Bayes method but for one list and I couldn't get the desired output:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b= [6,7,8,4,3,1]
print(a)
print(b)
b= []
for i in a:
  if i not in b:
    b.append(i)
print("New a:", a)
print("New b:", b)
```

Comment: Question is unclear as "Like if one list "a" has [1,2,3] and another list "b" has [4,5,6,2] then the output of "a" should remain the same but "b" should be changed to [4,5,6] removing [2] identifying it as a duplicate element in both the lists" but it should be a[1,3] and b[4,5,6]

Comment: @Shamim thanks for your reply. No, "a" list output should remain the same as it is which is [1,2,3] but only "b" list output should be changed by popping the duplicate element

Answer (score 0):

```
# Like if one list "a" has [1,2,3] and another list "b"
# has [4,5,6,2] then the output of "a" should remain the same
# but "b" should be changed to [4,5,6]
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6,2]

b=[x for x in b if x not in a]

print(f"{a=}\n{b=}")
>>>a=[1, 2, 3]
>>>b=[4, 5, 6]
```